# Swagger 2.0 request body use both ref and example

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0

In Swagger 2.0 (OpenAPI spec) is there any way to specify an "example" for a request body *and also specify the ref*?  I can do so for a response body.  My case is for a certain PUT the body is a ref, but the instance you'd put would differ from the schema's example value.

```
 - name: myObj
   in: body
   description: The information
   required: true
   schema:
     $ref: '#/definitions/SomeObject'
     example: 'some string that conforms to my ref'
```

Answer (score 0):

In OpenAPI 2.0 - no, not really. `$ref` overwrites any adjacent keywords, so the `example` will be ignored. Some tools support `x-example` or `x-examples` for parameters, so *depending on your tool* you might be able to use

```yaml
 - name: myObj
   in: body
   description: The information
   required: true
   schema:
     $ref: '#/definitions/SomeObject'
   x-example:
     property1: value1
     property2: value2
```

or

```yaml
 - name: myObj
   in: body
   description: The information
   required: true
   schema:
     $ref: '#/definitions/SomeObject'
   x-examples:
     application/json:
       property1: value1
       property2: value2
```

or something similar.

What you want is possible in **OpenAPI 3.0**:

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.0
...

paths:
  /something:
    put:
      requestBody:
        required: true
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/SomeObject'
            example:
              property1: value1
              property2: value2
```

This is supported in Swagger UI 3.17.4 and later.